# Zend Gdata get username

Tags: php, youtube-api

I am trying to use the Zend oAuth for the Youtube API, I have got the user authenticated by redirecting them to google and coming back with the access code, the problem is I am having trouble getting that users information.

If I use

```
$userProfile = $yt->getUserProfile("NAME");
```

Then I can get the info of that user however I want "NAME" to be the username of the logged in user something like $yt->username (doesn't work)

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$userProfile = $yt->getUserProfile("NAME")->getUsername();
```